# 'Insufficient Privileges' error while creating Force.com Site

Tags: force.com-sites, insufficient-privileges

While creating force.com site for an org, we are getting an error of 'Insufficient Privileges'. Seems one of an issue, any clue here?

Ps : I'm trying to create Site from Sys Admin login.

[image]

Comment: The only permission needed is "Customize Application", so assuming you have that as an admin, have you created your Domain to host the site?

Answer (score 0):

"Profiles" wasn't enabled in the trial org, hence I was receiving this one of kind error.

Raised case with salesforce and got "Profiles" setup option enabled which automatically fixed Site creation issue.